# Insert Statement with Dynamic SQL and Where NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic, sql-insert, not-exists

I have following in my stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

```
declare @sql as varchar(max)
set @sql='select col1,col2 from remote server'
```

What I am trying to do is

```
insert into mytable(col1,col2)
exec(@sql)
Where not exists
(select * from mytable where col1=?,col2=?)
```

This is not working. Is there any solution to this. My dynamic sql will be as it is as this is fetching data from some remote server using openquery. So I don;t have solution but to call `exec(@sql)` while inserting. Also not sure how to with what I should replace "?" in Where NOT Exists clause as the data is from dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this. It works. Don't forget to grant permissions.

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
set @sql='
insert [linkedserver].[database].[schema].[tablename] (col1, col2)
select @a, @b
where not exists (select 1 from [linkedserver].[database].[schema].[tablename]  
where col1 = @a and col2 = @b)
select * from [linkedserver].[database].[schema].[tablename]  
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@a int, @b int', 1,4
```